# Zoom breaks CSS

Tags: css, zooming

I the following javascript which creates a rectangle of 125 divs by 75 divs. As follows:

```
function createFlag() {
var flag;
var counter = 1;
var rowCounter = 1;
var divs = 10000;
flag = '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>';
for (var i = 0; i < divs; i++) {
    if (i % 125 === 0) {
        flag += '</ tr><tr>';
        rowCounter++;
        counter = rowCounter;
    } else flag += '<td id="pixel_' + counter + '" class="pixel"></td>';
    counter += 80;
}
flag += '</tr></table>';
$('#flag').append(flag);
}
```

And I have some CSS which works fine while no zoom is applied. The CSS uses % and em for sizes which I thought should mean that relative proportions would be kept. The problem is as soon as you zoom in or out the rectangle of divs distorts shape.

To see what I mean the url in question is here: [link here](http://pixelflag.com/)

How can I keep the proportions when zooming? All help appreciated of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table can't expand any more because the `#flag` div's width is `45%` of the `#container` div width, which itself is `50%` of the `<body>`. The width of the `<body>` doesn't change when you zoom, so the width of your table can't.

So you can either change the layout so that the form and the flag won't be float side by side, or just change `#container`'s width to `em`'s or `px`'s.

Comment: Thanks for that tip it helps! My table and div rectangle still don't stay quite the same relative size though (on my screen most notably at 90% and 110% zoom)